# Steal/borrow Visual Studio 2010 tabcontrol-template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, tabs, tabcontrol

I want/would like a TabControl with TabItem's I can close (with an x) and move around. If I also could move the tabitems to other screens it would be great. In fact I want it exactly as in VS2010 with docking and splitting side-by-side etc. But to implement all this by my self would take weeks. Thats life I suppose, but perhaps there is some way I could borrow the templates from VS2010? I tried snooping VS2010 but it wasnt working and I dont know if it would even if I could, I mean its not that snoop lets me extract the templates anyway. What other options do I have? Could Blend help me here? Reflector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about stealing VS2010 TabControl template,

but as a start here's a good tabcontrol template I think :
http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2010/02/15/WPF-TabControl-series-Part-4-Closeable-TabItems.aspx

This one makes the tab closable and keep them on one line, with a special scrollbar.
Also, there is a kind of combobox on the right of the tabs which list all the tabs, like in VS2010.

What is missing is the possibility to move tabs around (could be done I think), and to move tabs to other screen, as if there where other windows (harder to do I think).

Anyway, let me know if you find something better :-)

See you.